# Store array of char pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to read in a file of text and store it inside an array using a C function, but running into pointer difficulties:

The file to be read is in the format \t:

France     Baguette

China      Rice

Japan      Sushi

etc.

My code is the following, but currently only shows the last entry in the file:

```
void func(char *a[])
{
     FILE *dic = fopen("dic.log", "r");
     char *country = malloc(30);
     char *food = malloc(30);
     int i = 0;
     while (fscanf(dic, "%s %s", country, food) == 2)
     {
          a[i] = country;
          a[i+1] = food;
          i+=2;
     }
     fclose(dic);
}

int main (int argc, char*argv)
{
     char *b[6];
     func(b);

     printf("%s %s\n", b[0], b[1]);
     printf("%s %s\n", b[2], b[3]);

     return 1;
 }
```

I want the function to populate array 'b' in the following manner:

b[france,baguette,china,rice,japan,sushi]

Comment: please pass the size of the array to your function, and check boundary condition (where you have i+=2, change to if(i+=2>size) break;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happenimg because you have allocated memory to `country` and `food` only once.

Use malloc inside the while loop which will allocate both of them memory to individually store the values.

Your code will somewhat look like

```
void func(char *a[])
{
     FILE *dic = fopen("dic.log", "r");
     char *country;
     char *food;
     int i = 0;
     while (!feof(dic))
     {
          country = (char*)malloc(30);
          food = (char*)malloc(30);
          fscanf(dic, "%s%s", country, food);
          a[i] = country;
          a[i+1] = food;
          i+=2;
     }
     fclose(dic);
}

int main (int argc, char*argv)
{
     char *b[6];
     func(b);

     printf("%s %s\n", b[0], b[1]);
     printf("%s %s\n", b[2], b[3]);

     return 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to malloc for each read. At the moment you're overwriting the same memory (that you malloced at the beginning) with each new read.
Try this:

```
 while (fscanf(dic, "%s %s", country, food) == 2)
 {
      a[i] = country;
      a[i+1] = food;
      i+=2;

      // Reassign so we can re-read
      country = malloc(30);
      food = malloc(30);
 }
```

It's not a very elegant solution as you'll need to free up the last mallocs after the last read - but it proves the point!